# SSMS replace numbers in string with sequential 123

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Company uses naming conventions for different invoice transactions. For example, a systematic sales order is CINVBxxx563901 whereas a free text invoice is FTINVBxxx00120674-DM. I would like to replace all numbers with a sequential 123--for example, CINVBxxx563901 to CINVBxxx123456 and FTINVBxxx00120674-DM to FTINVBxxx12345678-DM. The numbers are always continous but length and position vary.

The following works but only if string ends in numbers.

```
TRIM('1234567890' FROM [INVOICE])+LEFT('12345678901234567890',LEN([INVOICE]),LEN(TRIM('1234567890' FROM [INVOICE]))
```

I want to be able to GROUP BY the invoice naming convention, line of business, and a simple COUNT(*) but best I've come up with is nested REPLACE number for 0 then SUBSTITUTE 0 in Excel but there has to be a better way.

For context, dataset is currently 82m records. Thanks for any help.

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: @ThomA Thanks updated tags. Using Microsoft SQL Server 18.

Comment: There isn't a SQL Server 18; we only got SQL Server 16 (2022) last year.

Comment: is it always one number stretch in the invoice? you can probably use patindex('%[0-9]%', invoicenumber) to get the first occurance and then patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse(invoicenumber)) to get the last occurance of number and then do your thing on it

Comment: @siggemannen Thank you for the idea! Was able to tweak for my use and posted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume a max length (looks like 20 is already assumed in the Q) then one way would be to use `TRANSLATE` to first convert all digits to `1` and then simply `REPLACE` the 20 possible strings in descending length order.(or 19 of them as no need to replace the single digit `'1'`)

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X-dVwzg4)

```
SELECT *, 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              TRANSLATE(INVOICE, '023456789', '111111111')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 20),'12345678901234567890')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 19),'1234567890123456789')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 18),'123456789012345678')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 17),'12345678901234567')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 16),'1234567890123456')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 15),'123456789012345')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 14),'12345678901234')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 13),'1234567890123')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 12),'123456789012')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 11),'12345678901')
         ,REPLICATE('1', 10),'1234567890')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  9),'123456789')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  8),'12345678')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  7),'1234567')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  6),'123456')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  5),'12345')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  4),'1234')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  3),'123')
         ,REPLICATE('1',  2),'12')
FROM (
    VALUES('FTINVBxxx00120674-DM'), 
          ('CINVBxxx563901'), 
          ('Foo-7')) V(INVOICE)
```

`TRANSLATE` requires at least SQL Server 2017 but you must be on at least that from the `TRIM('1234567890' FROM` in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my stab it, and this one does not limit to the length of the digits in the invoice. Only make sure that you do not apply this formula on invoice that does not have a number in it; I've used a WHERE clause to filter that out, you could use a CASE statement.

I've given the comments in the SQL statement. The main formula is in the last column, the other columns are just for debugging.

But TBH, best is you write a function which would be more readable and easy to manage.

```
DECLARE @Invoice VARCHAR(20) = 'FTINVBxxx00120674-DM'
DECLARE @NumberSeries VARCHAR(50) = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

SELECT  
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice) [START OF NUMBER],
    LEN(@Invoice) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Invoice)) + 1 [END OF NUMBER], 
    (LEN(@Invoice) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Invoice)) + 1) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice) - 1) [NUMBER OF DIGITS], 
    SUBSTRING(@Invoice, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice), (LEN(@Invoice) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Invoice)) + 1) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice) - 1)) [NUMBER TO REPLACE], 
    
    REPLACE(@Invoice, 
    SUBSTRING(@Invoice, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice), (LEN(@Invoice) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Invoice)) + 1) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice) - 1)) /* [NUMBER TO REPLACE] */, 
    SUBSTRING(@NumberSeries, 1, (LEN(@Invoice)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@Invoice))+1)- (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice)-1)) /* CUT NUMBER UPTO THE [NUMBER OF DIGITS] */ )  [FINAL OUTPUT]
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Invoice) > 0  -- MAKE SURE THE ABOVE FORMULA IS USED ONLY WHEN NUMBER IS PRESENT ( COULD BE USED AS CASE STATEMENT  )
```

Output -

```
START OF NUMBER END OF NUMBER NUMBER OF DIGITS NUMBER TO REPLACE    FINAL OUTPUT
--------------- ------------- ---------------- -------------------- --------------------
10              17            8                00120674             FTINVBxxx12345678-DM
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! Played with @siggemannen idea (thanks! hadn't thought this way) and came up with following that works for all of my records including when all numbers (no alpha char).

```
  LEFT([INVOICE],(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',        [INVOICE]) -1))
+ LEFT('12345678901234567890',
   LEN([INVOICE])
-                (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',        [INVOICE]) -1)
-                (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE([INVOICE]))-1))
+RIGHT([INVOICE],(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE([INVOICE]))-1))
```